# How fast swap between buffers?

Tags: buffers, window-splitting

Windows 10, Emacs 25.1

I have 4 open buffers.

Here

[image]

To switch from buffer "**file_1.txt**" to buffer "**file_2.txt**" I use standard command `windmove-right`. It is bound to `<M-right>`.
[image]

To switch from buffer "**file_2.txt**" to buffer "**file_3.txt**" I use standard command `windmove-down`. It is bound to `<M-down>`.

And so on. It's very comfortable. Nice.

But what if I need to SWAP buffers "**file_1.txt**" and "**file_2.txt**"?

The result must be like this:

[image]

To do this I use package `ace-window` and command `ace-swap-window`.

Here steps.
1. Start command `ace-swap-window`

[image]

2. Select number of windows I want to swap - "**3**"
   [image]
3. And as result the buffer "**file_1.txt**" and "**file_2.txt**" was swapped.
   [image]

But I think it's very slow.

Is it possible when I stay on buffer "**file_1.txt**" and press, e.g. `<M-S-right>` to swap buffer "**file_1.txt**" and "**file_2.txt**".

Or when I stay on buffer "**file_2.txt**" and press, e.g. `<M-S-down>` to swap buffer "**file_2.txt**" and "**file_4.txt**".

I think it will be very fast and convenient.

Comment: I know is not the answer you're looking for. But wouldn't be faster just to key bind Ace swap to M-p? , that way you would just have to do M-p 3. That's what I actually do. This way you don't have to move your hand to the cursor

Comment: I think about this...but it slow. I need set like this https://github.com/lukhas/buffer-move

Comment: No problem!. You could always create your own package to do what your looking for. I don't know if any existing package does exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: A [package](http://github.com/emacsmirror/buffer-move.git) already exists for this

Comment: @InHarmsWay This package is closed and not work. I get error Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable closed)
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "d:/Programs/emacs/.emacs.d/elpa/buffer-move-20160615.1103/buffer-move.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 7

Comment: The package buffer-move works for me still. What version of emacs, OS are you on?  How did you install it?

Comment: @InHarmsWay Yes, I install it from Melpa (by Emacs package manager). Windows 10, Emacs 25.1

Comment: @Alexei I see no such error when using the file from the source. I don’t use Melpa. Perhaps you can compare the repository version to the one you’re trying to eval?

Comment: @InHarmsWay Yes, when using the file from source https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lukhas/buffer-move/master/buffer-move.el   - then it's work fine.

Answer (score 1):

This is quick and dirty solution. It uses `windmove` and `ace-window` -- as I am lazy to come up with my own window functions:

```
(require 'windmove)
(require 'ace-window)

(defun swap-windows (dir)
  (let ((other-window (windmove-find-other-window dir nil nil)))
    (cond ((null other-window)
           (user-error "No window %s from selected window" dir))
          ((and (window-minibuffer-p other-window)
                (not (minibuffer-window-active-p other-window)))
           (user-error "Minibuffer is inactive"))
          (t
           (aw-swap-window other-window)))))


(defun swap-windows-right ()
  (interactive)
  (swap-windows 'right))

(defun swap-windows-left ()
  (interactive)
  (swap-windows 'left))

(defun swap-windows-down ()
  (interactive)
  (swap-windows 'down))

(defun swap-windows-up ()
  (interactive)
  (swap-windows 'up))
```

Bind those functions (`swap-windows-right/left/down/up`) to whatever keys you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another hand-rolled solution. It requires only `ace-window`, the rest of the functions are built-in

```
(defun swap-vertical ()
  (interactive)
  (if (window-in-direction 'above)
      (aw-swap-window (window-in-direction 'above))
    (aw-swap-window (window-in-direction 'below))))

(defun swap-horizontal ()
  (interactive)
  (if (window-in-direction 'right)
      (aw-swap-window (window-in-direction 'right))
    (aw-swap-window (window-in-direction 'left))))
```

I'm expecting that you will have at most two rows and two columnns of windows in a pane. Calling `swap-horizontal` will swap left or right, and `swap-vertical` will swap up or down. I find that for these kinds of actions I like to have the same key do the forward and reverse direction, so I can bounce back and forth. You could also make separate functions for each direction if you prefer. In that case, they would be even simpler:

```
(defun swap-right ()
  (interactive)
  (aw-swap-window (window-in-direction 'right)))
```

and so on for each direction.